# Visual Studio can't open any C++ header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've just started using Microsoft Visual Studio to code with C++, and even when writing a simple code like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using std namespace 

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I end up getting 300 or something errors.

[image]

Comment: What is `using std namespace`?

Comment: Did you search the the error messages online?

Comment: The errors likely mean you don't have your IDE's includes directories setup correctly.  Or, maybe the files were installed using a different user account than the one that is compiling the code, and the installing user didn't setup the files with the correct permissions to allow access to other users.  Hard to say.  You should use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see WHY the files can't be opened (because they don't exist, etc)

Comment: just use "using namespace std"

Comment: Whats the contents of the file `allocator.h` in the `Header Files`-Filter in your project? Why are there files in it anyway if you only want to compile `Source.cpp` with the code shown?

Comment: what kind of project did you select ion the main menu? did you choose win32 console or sth like that or something else? did you remove any files, etc from the solution yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not specified the paths to your include and lib directories.

In VS IDE, select Menu /Project/Property/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories: ( these paths will be slightly different in your case and later you will know how to allow your IDE to include these paths by default to your projects)

Include directories:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\atlmfc\include

Lib directories:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\lib\amd64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64

Comment: Hi, I tried going to the directories you mentioned and found out that they didn't exist on my computer. Should I create them and put all the header file in them?

What I currently have as the directories path is C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++. I'm not sure if that is a valid directory path but when I downloaded MinGW it installed everything I believe.

Comment: These directories should have been created after successful installation of your VS. Please search for `VC\atlmfc\include` and `VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64` directories in your system, enter the absolute paths in your include and lib directories.

Comment: Something must've gone wrong then. I just tried completely removing VS from my system by removing it, its registry, and all it's files from appdata and doing a clean re-installation and I still didn't manage to get the two folders you mentioned. 
I'm using the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio Community by the way.